# what is th homology group of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

what is the 0'th homology group of $\mathbb{Q}$ I mean $ H_{0}(\mathbb{Q})$?as the 0'th homology group is counting the path component of the space so it should be infinite direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$,and that exactly the place I feel doubt and I asked myself is it true for infinitely points?

so please help me and guide me ,thank you very much.

Comment: have a look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50319/homotopy-homology-groups-of-rationals)

Comment: @AymanHourieh: How is $\pi_0(\mathbb{Q}) = \mathbb{Q}$ wrong? It looks correct to me.

Comment: @AymanHourieh: 1/ $\pi_0$ is a functor usually defined on topological spaces, not pointed spaces; 2/ $\mathbb{Q}$ is in particular a pointed space (being a group), so the identification isn't abusive; 3/ $\mathbb{Q}$ is an H-space and even a topological group, so $\pi_0$ *does* have more structure. In any case, there is a canonical bijection of pointed sets $\pi_0(\mathbb{Q}, q_0) \cong (\mathbb{Q}, q_0)$, basically the identity.

Comment: @AymanHourieh: Yes, I got a bit carried away for my first point; it's also common to view $\pi_0$ as a pointed set. Point 3/ still stands though: $\pi_0(\mathbb{Q}, 0) = \mathbb{Q}$ in almost every possible way (not as topological spaces though!).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi You have convinced me. I'll delete my comments in a few minutes. :)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi can $\pi_0$ not be given the compact open topology in which case I believe $\pi_0(\mathbb{Q},0)$ is actually homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ right? (Haven't worked out the details yet so I could be wrong.)

Comment: @DanielRust: I think you're right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the definition of singular homology, the $n$th homology group of $\mathbb{Q}$ is trivial except for $H_0(\mathbb{Q};\mathbb{Z})$ which is countably infinitely freely generated abelian, that is $H_0(\mathbb{Q};\mathbb{Z})\cong\displaystyle\bigoplus_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{Z}$.

(really the only cases where you can directly apply the definition of singular homology is when your space is totally disconnected).

Comment: (+1) I'd use $H_0(\Bbb Q; \Bbb Z)$ (with a semicolon) in this context. $H_0(\Bbb Q, \Bbb Z)$ can also denote relative homology.

Comment: Very true. Thanks.

Comment: see a related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096835/betti-number-and-the-homology-class-what-determines-the-coefficient-q