# Betti number and the homology class - what determines the coefficient $Q$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betti_number#Definition):

For a non-negative integer $k$, the $k$th Betti number $b_k(X)$ of the space $X$ is defined as the rank (number of generators) of the abelian group $H_k(X)$, the $k$th homology group of $X$.

Equivalently, one can define it as the vector space dimension of $H_k(X; Q)$ since the homology group in this case is a vector space over $Q$.

> **My question 1** is about the the $k$th Betti number as the vector space dimension $H_k(X; Q)$: what determines $Q$?

-

Note add: now I more appreciate that the $Q$ is more like a coefficient for the mapping from $X$ to $Q$, correct?

> **My question 2**: If I take $Q=\mathbb{Z}_N \equiv \mathbb{Z}/(N \mathbb{Z})$, then for a genus-g 2-dimensional Riemann surface $\Sigma$, I should have 
>   $$H_1(\Sigma; \mathbb{Z}_N)=\prod^{2g}_1 \mathbb{Z}_N,$$
>    correct?
>   So,
>   $$|H_1(\Sigma; \mathbb{Z}_N)|=|\prod^{2g}_1 \mathbb{Z}_N|=N^{2g},$$
>   correct?
>
> **My question 2'**: more genereally, for a generic **compact manifold with boundaries**, does this formula work:
>   $$H_1({M},Z_k) =\prod_{k=1}^{b_1({M})} Z_k?$$
>   so
>   $$|H_1({M},Z_k)| =k^{b_1({M})}?$$
>
> **My question 3**: If I take $Q=\mathbb{Z}_N \equiv \mathbb{Z}/(N \mathbb{Z})$, then for a generic manifold $X$, should I have 
>   $$H_k(X; \mathbb{Z}_N)=\prod^{b_k(X)}_1 \mathbb{Z}_N?$$
>   So,
>   $$|H_k(X; \mathbb{Z}_N)|=|\prod^{b_k(X)}_1 \mathbb{Z}_N|=N^{b_k(X)}?$$
>   Here $b_k(X)$ is the $k$-th Betti number of the space $X$. Is my result correct?

Comment: $Q$ denotes the rational numbers.

Comment: That is not what the rank of an abelian group means. Rank means the number of generators of the torsion-free part.

Comment: @  Qiaochu Yuan, are you saying the Wikipedia statement is incorrect? Would you mind to correct the Wikipedia statement further? thanks so much.

Comment: Yes, the parenthetical is incorrect. Click the link to the article on rank to see that Wikipedia's own article on rank agrees with Qiaochu's.

Comment: @ Qiaochu Yuan and @  Mike Miller, many thanks, can someone fix the Wiki page?

Comment: @ Mike Miller, what if one choose $Q$ to be a $\mathbb{Z}_N$ group? What is special about $\mathbb{Z}_N$? (here $\mathbb{Z}_N=\mathbb{Z}/(N\mathbb{Z})$)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You ask a lot of different questions...

---

$\newcommand\Z{\mathbb{Z}}\newcommand\Q{\mathbb{Q}}$**Question 1**: For starters, the rank of an abelian group is the maximal cardinality of a linearly independent subset. Not the number of generators (see the comments). So for example the rank of $\Z/2\Z$ is zero. Equivalently, the rank $r$ of $A$ is the maximal cardinality such that there is an embedding $\Z^{(r)} = \bigoplus_r \Z \to A$ (you have to be careful with direct sums vs. products when $r$ is infinite).

Now the [universal coefficient theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_coefficient_theorem) tells you that:
$$H_n(X; \Q) \cong \operatorname{Tor}(H_{n-1}(X), \Q) \oplus H_n(X; \Z) \otimes \Q$$
You can use this to show that the dimension of $H_n(X; \Q)$ (over $\Q$) will be equal to the rank of $H_n(X; \Z)$. This is because the dimension of $H_n(X; \Z) \otimes \Q$ is the rank of $H_n(X; \Z)$. Meanwhile tensoring by $\Q$ is exact ($\Q$ is flat because it is the localization of $\Z$ at $(0)$), so $\operatorname{Tor}(-, \Q)$ is always zero.

---

**Question 2**: Yes, use the universal coefficient theorem again, using that $H_0(\Sigma_g) = \Z$ and $H_1(\Sigma_g) = \Z^{2g}$.

---

**Question 3**: Now, this one is not true. In fact if you look at the UCT (again...), you'll see why: $(\Z/N\Z)^{b_k}$ is only a part of the result (that corresponds to $\Z^{b_k} \otimes \Z/N\Z$), but there can be other factors. For example the rank of $H_i(\mathbb{RP}^n; \Z)$ is zero for all $i > 0$, but $H_i(\mathbb{RP}^n; \Z/2\Z) = \Z/2\Z$ for all $0 \le i \le n$.

Comment: Thanks, you are almost answering all the questions. I like to make sure: is $H_1(\mathcal{M},Z_k) =\prod_{k=1}^{b_1(\mathcal{M})} Z_k$ for a generic manifold $\mathcal{M}$?

Comment: I add question 2', would you mind to answer it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @mystery No, that's false. But if you have a new question, please ask a new question, don't edit your old one to include it.

Comment: Thanks, I did focus on a single question in another post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1099106/homology-class-and-betti-number-for-a-compact-manifold-with-boundaries

Comment: @  Najib Idrissi: How about if I restrict to the compact orientable manifold with boundaries? (such as a cylinder, etc.) I think that orientable manifolds and non-orientable manifolds matter. The reason is that the counter example for the projective plane $RP^2$ is exactly that case --- with torsion, for the non-orientable manifolds (e.g. projective plane $RP^2$).

Comment: @ Najib Idrissi: You may need to clarify or edit your notation: $H_i(\mathbb{RP}^2; \Z/2\Z) = \Z/2\Z$ for all $0 \le i \le n$, what is your $n$ and what is your $k$ in $b_k$. The notation is inconsistent.

Comment: @mystery I corrected the exponent. Once again if you have a new, different question, ask it in a question, not in these comments... I don't necessarily have the time to answer all your questions and there are plenty of users able to answer them on this website...

Comment: @  Najib Idrissi: No, because I haven't been able to fully digest your claim. Especially the $RP^n$ part. I need to make sure the relevsncy of this part: "$H_i(\mathbb{RP}^n; \Z)$ is zero for all $i > 0$, but $H_i(\mathbb{RP}^n; \Z/2\Z) = \Z/2\Z$ for all $0 \le i \le n$".

Comment: @mystery It is a counterexample to the claim of your question 3...