# Homology class and Betti number for a compact manifold with boundaries

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, betti-numbers

If I take $Q=\mathbb{Z}_N \equiv \mathbb{Z}/(N \mathbb{Z})$, for a genus-g 2-dimensional Riemann surface $\Sigma$, I should have 
$$H_1(\Sigma; \mathbb{Z}_N)=\prod^{2g}_1 \mathbb{Z}_N,$$
So,
$$|H_1(\Sigma; \mathbb{Z}_N)|=|\prod^{2g}_1 \mathbb{Z}_N|=N^{2g}.$$

> **Question a**: more generally, for a generic **compact manifold with boundaries: $M$**, does this formula work:
>   $$H_1({M},Z_k) =\prod_{k=1}^{b_1({M})} Z_k?$$
>   so
>   $$|H_1({M},Z_k)| =k^{b_1({M})}?$$

-

> **Question b**: Are there extra terms that are missing in the formula above? Can I intuitive see $H_1(\Sigma; \mathbb{Z}_N)$ and $H_1({M},Z_k)$ for a genus-g 2-dimensional Riemann surface $\Sigma$ and for a generic compact manifold $M$ with boundaries in terms of the number of independent cycles of winding around non-contactable loops?

Answer (score 4):

The answer to **question a** is not always, and the answer to **question b** is that there may be missing terms.

What you want is the universal coefficients theorem for homology. The general statement is that for any dimension $n$ (in your case $n=1$) and any coefficient group $Q$ (in your case $Q = \mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$), and any topological space $\Sigma$ there is a short exact sequence, here we have: 
$$0 \to H_n(\Sigma) \otimes Q \to H_n(\Sigma;Q) \to \mathrm{Tor}(H_{n-1}(\Sigma);Q) \to 0
$$
The coefficients in "$H_n(\Sigma)$" are, of course, $\mathbb{Z}$. And "Tor" denotes the torsion product operation.

In your case where $n=1$ we have $H_0(\Sigma) \approx \mathbb{Z}$ (assuming path connected for simplicity) and the torsion product term is trivial, so there are no missing terms from that source. But it is possible that $H_1(\Sigma)$ can have some torsion in which case the tensor product $H_1(\Sigma) \otimes Q$ may have missing terms. In particular the projective plane is a counterexample with $Q = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, because $b_1=0$.

But if $H_1(\Sigma)$ is torsion free then it works as with an oriented surface (boundary is irrelevant), namely, here we have: 
$$H_1(\Sigma;Q) \approx H_1(\Sigma) \otimes Q \approx \prod_1^{b_1} Q
$$

Comment: what if I focus on the orientable manifolds? not the non-orientable manifolds. Will it affect your answer then?

Comment: @mystery: It really does not matter.

Comment: @ studiosus: can you clarify? I think that orientable manifolds and non-orientable manifolds matter. The reason is that the counter example for the projective plane $RP^2$ is exactly that case --- with torsion, for the non-orientable manifolds (e.g. projective plane $RP^2$).

Comment: @ Lee Mosher: Thanks for your nice answer. I am about to give your the full credit. Just to make sure, you claim that if  for an oriented surface (compact oriented with or without boundaries), then $H_1(\Sigma)$ is torsion free, and then it works $H_1(\Sigma;Q) \approx H_1(\Sigma) \otimes Q \approx \prod_1^{b_1} Q$, correct?

Comment: @mystery: For instance, $RP^2$ is homotopy-equivalent to a compact oriented 2-dimensional manifold, namely, $RP^3$ minus an open ball (and $RP^3$ is oriented). On the other hand, $S^2$ is homotopy-equivalent to a non-orientable compact 3-manifold.

Comment: @mystery: Yes, this works for all compact oriented surfaces.